# Javascript: Do not wait for async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

Consider the following code snippet:

```
async function f() {
    console.log("entering");
    for (let i=0;i<=1e9;i++) {}
    console.log("quitting");
}

async function g() {
    console.log("before");
    f();
    console.log("after");
}

g();
```

I would expect the function `g()` to call `f()` **without** waiting for it to finish. Thus, I would expect the output to be

```
before
entering
after
quitting
```

However, `g()` actually waits for `f()` to finish. Why does this happen, when `f()` is supposed to be an async function?

Comment: There is no `await` within `f()` that would cause it to run asynchronously. `async` just means that you can use `await` within the function.

Comment: You have to use `await` . Check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description

Comment: It seems that you have some misconceptions about what the `async/await` mechanism means.

Comment: @ArmedinKuka — You can only await a promise. A for loop is not a promise.

Comment: @Pointy This is well possible and is mainly the reason for my question...

Comment: @PhilippImhof [here is a pretty good introduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)